# Working Alone Satellite Devices

Tags: satellite, hardware-recommendations, health

I am researching potential tech solutions for personnel to use out in remote areas in the event of an emergency situation.

I have been told I need to

1) find satellite based solutions as the phone network is not reliable.

2) Find a device that facilitates user check-in at set intervals so that an alert is raised if they fail to check in and an escalation procedure can begin.

I am struggling to find a single device that fulfills both these criteria. Can anyone make me recommendation or at least explain why these two criteria seem to be mutually exclusive in most devices. I know the check-in exists for phone apps, why can't it work for satellite based devices?

Answer (score 1):

[The Spot Gen 3](http://www.findmespot.com/en/index.php?cid=100) is an inexpensive solution that will do what you are asking.  It will not notify the user that they need to send a message out, but a cheap wrist watch can solve that problem.  At the lowest subscription level a position is reported every 10 minutes, the user initiates a message manually to a pre-configured distribution list.  Who ever is monitoring this device should be responsible for whether or not they need to go look for the individual when some threshold is met.  Although, You could automate this fairly easily by parsing the messages that are viewed either publicly or privately on the spot website.

I do not have any stake in this company but I do own one of the devices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Spot Gen 3 is one of the devices I am trialling in the near future. I have found mixed reviews but overall I am hopeful. The work around you recommend regarding the wrist watch is nice and simple but also likely to be something that will be frowned upon by the Steering group however. A great suggestion, thank you.

Comment: I think automating a message is not a good idea...If X person is injured and the message "I'm OK" is being sent automatically every hour then its not going to help the individual having the problem.  as for my review...it does what it says it does nothing more nothing less, and works in my or bag or pocket.

Comment: The message sending is not automated, it is the alert requesting a user to send a message which is automated. If the alert goes off and after a set time period no message is sent then the escalation process can begin to check on the person.

Comment: You would probably still want to do that on the back end..For example if you tell the user they need to check in every hour and they miss 2 checkins then maybe you need to go and get them.   You might also want to define what remote is if we are talking about the amazon this won't work...to much tree cover